# Docker: Container should get access to directory of another container

Tags: docker

I need to get access to a directory from docker container to another docker container.

In the first container I am running a nodeJS application and in the `tests/e2e` folder there are my e2e tests and the configuration for webdriverIO.
Also it I don't need a persistend volume - like I've done it so far. I just need the test files as long as both container are running.

```
$ docker run
  --name app_stage
  --volume tests:/app/tests
  --detach
  app:stage
```

This is the Dockerfile to that application

```
RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build
EXPOSE 3000
ENV NODE_ENV production
CMD next start
```

In the second container I'm running webdriverIO, which needs to get the tests and the configuration of the first container stored there in `app/tests`

```
$ docker run
  --rm
  --volumes-from app_stage
  webdriverio wdio
```

But this is not working as I do not see the needed directory in the second container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, specify `VOLUME`variable in you dockerfile:

```
RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build
EXPOSE 3000
ENV NODE_ENV production
VOLUME /app/tests
CMD next start
```

Use your first command to start app_stage container then start webdriverio container with the second command.